# Updating a table using SQL function (data dependent on source) in the INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-function, cross-apply

I have this `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE BLDG SET
    BLDG.BLOC1 = T.BLOC1,
    BLDG.BLOC2 = T.BLOC2,
    BLDG.BLOC3 = T.BLOC3
FROM BLDG B
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM dbo.INVENTORIZE(B.B_ID)) T
ON B.B_ID = T.B_ID
```

which uses a simple function that - run separately - returns:

```
B_ID   BLOC1   BLOC2   BLOC3
-----------------------------
1      2.00    3.00    NULL
```

The above update statement returns an error "The multi-part identifier "B.B_ID" could not be bound." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `dbo.INVENTORIZE` a table-valued function?

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE B SET
    BLOC1 = T.BLOC1,
    BLOC2 = T.BLOC2,
    BLOC3 = T.BLOC3
FROM dbo.BLDG B
CROSS APPLY dbo.INVENTORIZE(B.B_ID) AS T;
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, now I just have to figure out how :)

Comment: When the table-valued function depends on input from the source, you "join" to the results of the function by using cross apply (or outer apply).

Comment: So, no dependency from source = JOIN, with dependency from source = APPLY?

Comment: @greener in general, yes, I think I can agree.